# Add a progress bar to CSV.read function in Julia?

Tags: dataframe, csv, julia, dataframes.jl

I have a txt file such as `xx.txt` with about several hundred million rows.

When I use `CSV.read('xx.txt', DataFrame)` to read the data into `Julia`, it takes about 10 minutes.

I'm wondering whether it is possible to add a progress bar or something to show
that the reading process is undergoing?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a general advice: if you are dealing with such long load times, it might be a better idea to read the file chunk-wise, see for examples https://csv.juliadata.org/stable/reading.html#CSV.Chunks This can also be used with together with e.g. https://github.com/timholy/ProgressMeter.jl to display a progressbar. `CSV.read` does not propagate the progress to the outer scope, so you'll not be able to display it with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion provided by tamasgal. All honours are his.
In following code lines, I've implemented his idea. Now we can see the progress bar. The reading process could also be highly speeded up. With my laptop, it takes only about two minutes, five times shorter than the original method.

```
using CSV, DataFrames
using ProgressMeter

function Txt2DF(TxtDt; ntasks = 100)
    df = DataFrame()
    DataChunks = CSV.Chunks(TxtDt, ntasks = ntasks)
    @showprogress for chunk in DataChunks
        append!(df, DataFrame(chunk), promote = true)
    end
    return df
end

Txt2DF("xx.txt")
```